# Is it possible to convert the following jquery to css?

Tags: html, checkbox

I have the following snippet:

```js
$(".status").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(this).next().show();
  } else {
    $(this).next().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">
  <input type="checkbox" class="status" checked />
  <div class="infoCont">....lot of stuff......</div>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <input type="checkbox" class="status" checked />
  <div class="infoCont">....lot of stuff......</div>
</div>
```

I achieved this result using jQuery but I want to ask if it is possible to achieve the same using pure css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following code.

```
    .info>.infoCont {
    display:none;
}
.info>.status:checked + .infoCont {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad forgot an important piece of the puzzle, try now

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the trick I will accept your answer as soon as I can. Unfortunately I cannot upvote you because I dont have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```css
.example + span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.example:checked + span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="example"><span>Hello</span><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example"><span>World</span><br>
```